How is a vector name and gender connected?
> Name <- c("anu", "ashok", "kavin", "tharun")
> genderr <- c("F", "M", "M")
> Name[genderr == "M"]
[1] "ashok" "kavin"

The data Name and genderr are not connected using a data frame. But when I try to retrieve names of males, I'm able to retrieve the names. Is it internally connected?
I was expecting that the two objects must be connected using a data frame, to retrieve values of each other. But here i did not use any dataframe,still i'm able to retrieve. Are they internally connected

Name and genderr differ in length. Is that intended?

You create a boolean vector inside the bracket, and subset your data, that's all. No magic.
> genderr == "M"
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
> Name[c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)]
[1] "ashok" "kavin"

If the subset would be longer it gets filled with NAs.
> Name[c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)]
[1] "ashok"  "kavin"  "tharun" NA       NA       NA   

Note, that the vector gets recycled, if it's shorter; so with
> Name[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
[1] "ashok"  "tharun"

we actually get
> Name[c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]
[1] "ashok"  "tharun"

And, this is a feature, not a bug :)

Important here is that data.frames are not "internally connected" as you think. They are roughly simply a collection of vectors in which checks for equal length are made.
